# Oracle BPM, Workspace

Tags: oracle, business-process-management, oracle-bpm-suite

I recently have started working with oracle bpm and trying to make some changes on my workspace page which will be shown to the users.
I want to customize the name of the application that I deployed and change it as I prefer, for example removing its version.
I am trying to do this with adding jQuery in the jspx file inside "\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_SOA1\soa\applications\OracleBPMWorkspace.ear", is there any other way that does not need to change jspx file?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different questions here.
1. How to customize a custom developed application?
2. How to customize built-in applications, such as BPM Workspace?

For the first you can change the title in the JDeveloper (BPM Studio), just right click your initiator process and in the name field type in whatever name you want to see in the applications link in the BPM Workspace;

For the second case, when you want to customize the BPM Workspace you can start with this https://java.net/projects/oraclebpmsuite11g/downloads/directory/Samples/bpm-CustomizingWorkspace/

Let me know if you have any questions.